# Maven Build- error in eclipse build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

How can i build `maven` `WebApplication` in eclipse?

I tried below,
project-> rightclick-> Run as-> Maven build

here its coming a window for giving `Goal` and `Profile`

I am getting error below,

```
lifecycle phase "Snapshot-1.0". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>.
```

What i should give as `Goal` & `Profile`? and how it will affect on pom.xml?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Give "clean install" or "install" as the goal.  You won't need to give a profile unless your POM file defines profiles.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. How can change my pom.xml according to that?

Comment: Huh?  I didn't suggest that you should change your POM file.  I said - "You do not *need* to give a profile *unless* your POM file (already) defines profiles".

Comment: settings.xml is not avail in Maven. Then what i will do for tomcat configuration?

Comment: If you need a "settings.xml" file, create one - see http://maven.apache.org/settings.html.  (You won't find the settings.xml file in Maven Central because it contains details about *your* system, etc.)  It sounds like you need to read the Maven tutorial information - http://maven.apache.org/users/index.html

Comment: *"Then what i will do for tomcat configuration?"* - generally speaking, you put webapp configuration stuff into the Maven project that builds the webapp.  Stuff to configure the Tomcat server is out of scope of Maven.